# Ford Fulkerson algorithm increasing flow

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, ford-fulkerson

Regarding the [Ford Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) algorithm with the path `s-x-y-z-t` we had to find out how the flow along that path could be increased.

The problem I'm having is, that I don't know how one gets the values in the solution.
Can someone explain?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find an augmenting path in the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, we need to look at the [residual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Residuals), which essentially allows us to

- keep adding flow on nonsaturated edges or
- remove existing flow from edges.

It looks like your example consists of a subgraph, because the vertices X, Y and Z violate flow conservation (the sum of incoming flows should be zero at every vertex).

In your example, we can

- push 7 more along the SX edge;
- push 4 more along the XY edge;
- remove 3 units from the YZ edge;
- push 4 more units along the ZT edge.

Therefore, we can push at most 3 units from S to T without violating any capacity constraints. By doing that we end up with the flow network described in your second image.